# Compile for ios simulator and run UITest in 2 times

Tags: ios, command-line, ios-simulator, xcodebuild, xcode-ui-testing

I try to compile my app for UITesting and in a second time run the UITest on iOS simulator. But I need to do this in 2 times.

In one time I use :

```
xcodebuild -workspace './MyApp.xcworkspace' -scheme 'MyScheme' -derivedDataPath '~/Documents/derived_data/' -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,id=6EE927C0-FC0E-4235-8915-3BFF1F128B76,OS=9.2' build test | xcpretty
```

Any Idea how to copy and launch MyApp.app, MyAppUITests-Runner.app in the simulator?

Thanks.

Alak

Edit:

Anyway to launch something like :

```
xcrun simctl launch "UITest"
```

and get xcactivitylog from this ?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
xcodebuild -workspace App.xcworkspace -scheme "App-Scheme" -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6,OS=9.1' test
```

it will compile the App and run the UI Test in the simulator.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, but I'm looking for a way to compile and run UI Tests in 2 times.